# Unittest GUI client

Tags: .net, unit-testing, architecture

For my current project I develop a GUI that is used for configuring a server. 
The GUI is using some services to run commands.

Did you ever developed unit tests for a GUI client?
Can you suggest me some architectural approaches in order to have my project unittestable?

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't write unit tests for GUI clients. GUIs make my tests slow.

Instead split your client into a GUI skin on top of a set of classes. Search for PresentationModel or MVVM patterns for more information.
Once you've done that, you can write (listed in decreasing order of speed and volume)

- unit tests for the classes. **(fast - microseconds per test)**
- Acceptance tests that operate the client like a real user but operate under-the-skin/GUI by exercising the presenters or the ViewModels **(slower than unit tests)**
- a few sanity UI acceptance tests (that use a library like [White](http://white.codeplex.com)) that verify that the GUI is hooked up to the underlying classes correctly. **(slowest)**

Answer (score 1):

You may try libraries [Dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) for Linux or [Pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) for Windows - the tests I've written with those libs looked like: Click that button, then watch if the server state changes as expected.

Comment: I've been using White; Pywinauto seems interesting. What does it work off ? MS UI Automation Ids ?

Comment: It reads text labels from all on-screen windows and controls using pure WinAPI calls, then tries to compose some class hierarchy from that. So it won't work with apps that draw all GUI by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possibility of "gui-testing" your application with different tools that are developed for that, I would recommend using some [passive view](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html) patterns like [MVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) for WinForms or [MVVM(P)](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/10/18/agile-ui-development-in-net-table-of-contents/) for WPF.
By this way almost all intelligence is in the presenter, and by mocking away the view you can test it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Hey.
For 'desktop' application use [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) to test GUI from unit test framework. For web app use [Watin](http://watin.org/).